# windows can connect to mysql using navicat,but can not connect using mysql cmd or java jdbc,but linux is ok

Tags: mysql

In Windows client machine A which I have closed firewall ,and I can connect to mysql using navicat, but can not connect using mysql cmd or java jdbc.
in Navicat General window,I only need to enter

```
1.Connection Name
2.host name
3.port 
4.username 
5.password
```

and then can successfully connect.

while in windows command line.

```
mysql -h 212.xx.xx.xx -P 3306 -u db_view  dbpassword
```

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'db_view'@'180.173.xx.xx' (using password: YES) 


while in Linux client machine B,can connect to database by mysql command line .

Answer (score 0):

because mysql password contains special character ÷ ,windows does not support.while MAC or linux can support this character.